# Dots between label and input field

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to place between the `label` tag (aligned left) and the `input` tag (aligned right) dots or lines to help the user to select the correct input?

```
<label for="firstname">Firstname: </label><input type="text" size="55" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="">
```

Comment: Have you tried to put the dots?

Comment: can you show some pictorial example

Comment: there's absolutely nothing about this question that requires jQuery (or even plain javascript), so I'd recommend removing the tag. Maybe put `html` tag instead.

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/RSZnL/ If not, please provide us with a picture or drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simlpy a case of using the CSS `::after` selector.

This selector allows you to insert additional content after an element. In this case, we want to insert a load of dots after our `label` element. So we simply do this:

```
label::after {
    content:'....................................................................................................................';
}
```

Clearly this on its own won't be great, because it'll cause all sorts of word-wrap issues and/or push the input box out of position, so we need to deal with all that stuff too, but that's relatively trivial.

We use `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap` to hide the excess dots and prevent them from word-wrapping, and then we just use CSS `position` to make sure the `input` field is fixed to the right.

You may or may not need that many dots, but with the excess dots being hidden it shouldn't really matter as long as you have enough to cover the maximum you're ever going to need.

I've created a fiddle for you which does all of the above, and should be a complete solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/FU66q/1/

Hope that helps.

Comment: great - but is there a solution with dynamic amount of dots?

Comment: @mike: this solution hides the dots that aren't needed, so in effect it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

What about alternating background colors for the rows using something like

```
label:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Maybe something with the inputs as well so they continue all the way across (or put the whole label/input pair in a container of its own).

Answer (score 0):

You could also put the elements into rows and highlight the different rows.

**Sample**

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrh7Q/2/

**Other ideas / samples**

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrh7Q/

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrh7Q/1/

**HTML**

```
<label for="firstname">Firstname: </label>
<span class="dots"></span>
<input type="text" size="55" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="">
<br />
<label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
<span class="dots">&nbsp;</span>
<input type="text" size="55" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="">
```

**CSS**
    .dots {
       border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
       width: 25%;
       display: inline-block;
    }

Comment: also a good idea. but i want to have the dots between the elements in the same line - not between the rows